# Why apache cordova script codes are not supporting in my device?

Tags: android, apache, cordova, phonegap-build

I am creating an Android application using Apache cordova with platform version 5.2.2. Using this I am able to install apk in my device and also screens are displaying. But unable to run script codes such as device ready functions. This scripts are supporting is other devices but not my one. My Android device version is 5.0.2

Comment: Please show some logs and code.

Comment: problem solved.Error is in meta tag